# How to Hide selected group Column in Kendo Angular 6 Grid,

Tags: kendo-grid, angular6

I have a  requirement in which some selected group columns should be hidden, and rest group columns should display.

How can we achieve it using Kendo ui + Angular 6.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the [ColumnComponent's `hidden` input](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/hidden/#toc-using-built-in-options) to an expression that returns the respective boolean value after performing the required custom logic that will determine whether a column should be hidden or not.

The grouping configuration is available in the object the Grid `group` input is bound to.

Here is an example that demonstrates hiding all columns the data is grouped by, but ProductName:

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ynbmih?file=app/app.component.ts)